# How to get call stack info in SQL Server's catch block?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I have multiple errors in my query, and I use `try catch` and `error_message()` function in my catch block, I only get the last error message.

For example, if my errors are:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 14
There is already an object named 'IX_EntityTypeConfigs' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

in the catch block I just get:

```
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

How can I get the whole message?

I have searched and saw that this is a limitation of SQL Server, but articles belonged to 2014 and older than that.

I wonder if things has changed since.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's still correct. The recommended way is to rethrow the errors to the application via the `THROW` command and let the app handle it.

The best resource is still this article by [Erland Sommarskog - Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

You can also capture the errors with *Extended Events* (XE) `error_reported` (on SQL Server side). That would show you all the errors that were fired.

I blog about it here: [Investigating Errors With Extended Events](https://straightforwardsql.com/posts/investigating-errors-with-extended-events/).